# Are there any Drupal 7 modules for creating organizational charts?

Tags: 7, charts

Are there any Drupal 7 modules for creating organizational charts? So far I have only seen one for Drupal 6.

Any solution you might have used to incorporate organizational charts in Drupal 7 will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Google Charts module](http://drupal.org/project/google_chart_tools) for Drupal 7 now has support for [organizational charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/orgchart).

Answer (score 0):

Views Org Chart module for drupal 7 is good for building organizational charts. Various relations can be established and also support of custom queries![Sample Output Of Google Organization Chart].
https://www.drupal.org/project/views_org_chart